# How do I use same getter and setter properties and functions for different attributes of a class the pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got this class that I'm working on that stores Employees details.
I want all attributes to be protected and be set and gotten with specific logic, but not all in a unique way. I would like the same logic to apply to my `_f_name` and to my `_l_name` attributes, I would like the same logic perhaps to be applied to attributes that take in booleans and other general cases.

I've got this for the first attribute:

```
@property
def f_name(self):
    return self.f_name
@f_name.setter
def f_name(self, f_name):
    if f_name != str(f_name):
        raise TypeError("Name must be set to a string")
    else:
        self._f_name = self._clean_up_string(f_name)
        
@f_name.deleter
def available(self):
    raise AttributeError("Can't delete, you can only change this value.")
```

How can I apply the same functions and properites to other attributes?

Thaaaanks!

Comment: I mean without rewriting the same code (obviously :P )

Comment: Write a descriptor that encapsulates the requirements and use it for all those attributes.

Comment: As an aside, change `if f_name != str(f_name):` to `if not isinstance(f_name, str):` because you don't know in general if a type can be compared to the string representation of the type.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Worse, maybe `f_name` *could* be compared to its string representation and return `True` based on the definition of `f_name.__eq__`.

Comment: Since you're talking about cleaning up names, here's some required reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may seem like defining a subclass of `property` is possible, too many details of how a *particular* property work is left to the getter and setter to define, meaning it's more straightforward to define a custom property-like descriptor.

```
class CleanableStringProperty:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._private_name = "_" + name
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        # Boilerplate to handle accessing the property
        # via a class, rather than an instance of the class.
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return getattr(obj, self._private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError(f'{self.name} value must be a str')
        setattr(obj, self._private_name, obj._clean_up_string(value))

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete, you can only change this value.")
```

`__set_name__` constructs the name of the instance attribute that the getter and setter will use. `__get__` acts as the getter, using `getattr` to retrieve the constructed attribute name from the given object. `__set__` validates and modifies the value before using `setattr` to set the constructed attribute name. `__del__` simply raises an attribute error, independent of whatever object the caller is trying to remove the attribute from.

Here's a simple demonstration which causes all values assigned to the descriptor to be put into title case.

```
class Foo:
    f_name = CleanableStringProperty()
    l_name = CleanableStringProperty()

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.f_name = first
        self.l_name = last

    def _clean_up_string(self, v):
        return v.title()

f = Foo("john", "doe")
assert f.f_name == "John"
assert f.l_name == "Doe"
try:
    del f.f_name
except AttributeError:
    print("Prevented first name from being deleted")
```

It would also be possible for the cleaning function, rather than being somethign that `obj` is expected to provide, to be passed as an argument to `CleanableStringProperty` itself. `__init__` and `__set__` would be modified as

```
def __init__(self, cleaner):
    self.cleaner = cleaner

def __set__(self, obj, value):
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        raise TypeError(f'{self.name} value must be a str')
    setattr(obj, self._private_name, self.cleaner(value))
```

and the descriptor would be initialized with

```
class Foo:
    fname = CleanableStringProperty(str.title)
```

Note that `Foo` is no longer responsible for providing a cleaning method.

Answer (score 1):

A property is just an implementation of a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#simple-example-a-descriptor-that-returns-a-constant), so to create a custom property, you need an object with a `__get__`, `__set__`, and/or `__delete__` method.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Tuple

class ValidatedProperty:
    def __set_name__(self, obj, name):
        self.name = name
        self.storage = f"_{name}"
    
    def __init__(self, validation: Callable[[Any], Tuple[str, Any]]=None):
        """Initializes a ValidatedProperty object

        Args:
            validation (Callable[[Any], Tuple[str, Any]], optional): A Callable that takes the given value and returns an error string (empty string if no error) and the cleaned-up value. Defaults to None.
        """
        self.validation = validation

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.storage)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.validation: 
            error, value = self.validation(value)
            if error:
                raise ValueError(f"Error setting property {self.name}: {error}")

        setattr(instance, self.storage, value)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete, you can only change this value.")
```

Let's define an example class to use this:

```
class User:
    def __name_validation(value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            return (f"Expected string value, received {type(value).__name__}", None)

        return ("", value.strip().title())

    f_name = ValidatedProperty(validation=__name_validation)
    l_name = ValidatedProperty(validation=__name_validation)
    
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.f_name = fname

        self.l_name = lname
```

and test:

```
u = User("Test", "User")

print(repr(u.f_name)) # 'Test'

u.f_name = 123  # ValueError: Error setting property f_name: Expected string value, received int

u.f_name = "robinson " # Notice the trailing space
print(repr(u.f_name))  # 'Robinson'

u.l_name = "crusoe "
print(repr(u.l_name))  # 'Crusoe'
```

Comment: If you store the descriptor value on the descriptor itself, you prevent distinct objects from having different value. Create a second instance of `User` with different arguments, and see what that does to `u.f_name` and `u.l_name`.

Comment: @chepner I just discovered this myself and was in the process of making an edit, thanks!